# Verdaccio Installing on IIS server: Can not find iisnode-verdaccio on npmjs

Tags: verdaccio

I no longer find iisnode-verdaccio on npmjs when following the instructions of Installing on IIS for Verdaccio.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

for install the `verdaccio` on iis. follow this stages:

1. install `node.js`. (e.g: `version 12.14.0`)
2. install `python` with **powersell**.

   run this command

   `npm i -g --production windows-build-tools`

   then run

   `npm i -g node-gyp`
3. Get the Python.exe file path.
   default path:   `C:\Users\xxx\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe`
4. Add a new `Environment Variable` with name `PYTHON` and value: `C:\Users\xxx\windows-build-tools\python27`.
5. if `visual studio` is installed go to next stage. else install `Descktop development with c++` from vs setup.
6. install `verdaccio` (e.g: `version 4.4.0`)

   `npm i -g verdaccio@4.4.0`
7. install `iisnode` (e.g: `version 0.2.21`).
8. install `ApplicationRequestRouting` (e.g: `v3.0`).
9. copy `web.config` , `package.json`, `start.js` from [this](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/iss-server#packagejson)
10. finaly, reset iis and enjoy.

[more info](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/iss-server)

I hope is useful.